# Comparar existência de registro com data e data futura

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho a seguinte model

```
public class AgendaExame
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int PacienteId {get; set;}
    public int ExameId {get; set;}
    public DateTime Data {get; set;} 
    public DateTime ProximaData {get; set;}
}
```

O uso dessa model é salvar o exame e data que foi realizado, e quando será o próximo exame (`ProximaData`)

Seguindo estas informações salvas:

```
ID, PacienteId, ExameId,         DATA,      PROXIMADATA
1      1             1        01/01/2018    01/01/2019  
2      1             2        01/01/2018    01/01/2019  
3      1             1        31/12/2018    31/12/2019
```

Quando eu for filtrar entre `01/01/2019` à `31/01/2019` Eu preciso buscar os exames que determinados pacientes precisam realizar.

Entretanto, como vemos na linha 3, o paciente realizou com 1 dia de antecedência o exame, logo, sua próxima data é somente no dia `31/12`, então não deve constar no dia `01/01`

O que tentei até agora foi isso:

```
  var busca = db.AgendaExames.AsQueryable()
                .Where(x =>
                     x.ProximaData != null &&
                     DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ProximaData ) >= model.Inicio &&
                     DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ProximaData ) <= model.Fim);
```

Mas esse código só busca os que tenho à realizar, eu preciso ainda verificar se o paciente não fez o exame antecipadamente (como explicado acima)

Resumo: Salvar exame e controlar quando será seu próximo exame

Comment: O que sua consulta faz é selecionar todos 'AgendaExames' que tenham o 'ProximaData' e também a 'Data' entre o fim e inicio da data enviada na model. Pelo que você tentou explicar não entendi oque quer, mas só irá retornar o 1º e 3º registro nesse caso se a data enviada for de 01/01/2018 à 31/12/2019.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann Pois é, acredito que só com Where não irei conseguir. Mas é conforme expliquei, buscar os exames à realizar baseado na ProximaData, mas tenho que validar também, se ele não tem "ProximaData" em meses futuros...

Comment: Você consegue construir um exemplo mais claro? No seu código você comparou tanto ProximaData quanto Data, mas nesse seu último comentário você está comparando só o ProximaData. Se vc quer essa data ou qualquer data futura é só fazer uma segunda comparação com "OR" onde x.ProximaData > model.Fim

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann ignore meu código, ele realmente está errado

Answer (score 1):

Não sei exatamente oque você deseja fazer com as informações. Mas pelo que você explicou no comentário você quer validar de o ProximaData está dentro de um período e também se pra esse mesmo campo há data futura.

Para trazer essas informações você pode fazer essa alteração no código que está na sua pergunta:

```
var busca = db.AgendaExames.AsQueryable()
.Where(x =>
     x.ProximaData != null &&
     DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ProximaData ) >= model.Inicio &&
     DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ProximaData ) <= model.Fim ||
     DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ProximaData ) > model.Fim);
```

Mas não vi muito sentido nisso. Se for algo diferente tente explicar suas regras melhor.

De forma mais simplificada você poderia fazer apenas isso que traria todos registros dentro do período informado e período futuro também:

```
var busca = db.AgendaExames.AsQueryable()
    .Where(x =>
         x.ProximaData != null &&
         DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ProximaData ) >= model.Inicio);
```

Comment: agora ficou mais claro de entender? Estou quase abandonando essa solução e procurando outra alternativa mais fácil